# Extract max value and duplicate max value from a List<Map<String,int>> Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, duplicates, key, max

I want to extract max value's Key from [{'A':50},{'B':25},{'C':35},{'D':45}]. I also want to return if there are max duplicate Keys like [{'A':50},{'B':25},{'C':50},{'D':45}]. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `import 'dart:math' as math;

main() {
var d = [{'A':50},{'B':125},{'C':125},{'D':45}];
var i = d.map((m) => m.values.single);
var max = i.reduce(math.max);
print(max);
print(i.where((e) => e == max));
}`

Comment: Thanks. Can we extract the Keys instead of values with this?

Comment: sure: `d.where(....)` - of course you would need to change the `test` callback inside `where` method

Comment: Kinda stuck. Could you please share the code?. Thanks.

Comment: `var i2 = d.where((e) => e.values.single == max);`

Comment: Great. Thanks so much!